# Ubuntu 18.04 very laggy

Tags: 18.04, performance

My Ubuntu had been very laggy in the past few months, and the problem was gone for a while, but now it's coming back again. Whenever I type something in Terminal, Firefox, or any kind of editors, it takes 3 or 4 seconds for the words I typed to be appeared on the screen. So it's realy laggy.

If I use `HTOP` command to check the resources. I got this screenshot.

[image]

It looks like the Load average is high. but I don't really have anything running except browsers. I can see something is using 47% CPU, but I don't know this process.

Any ideas how I can fix this issue? I tried to restart the computer, but no help.